# DRV8889: Unexpected voltage drop at output

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, datasheet, stepper-motor, kirchhoffs-laws

I'm getting some unexpected behaviors when it comes to the voltage and current I see at the AOUTx and BOUTx pins. I must be missing something from my calculations from the datasheet.

Right now, I'm calculating the expected full-scale current as

$$I_\text{FS} = (V_\text{ref}/K_v) \cdot TRQ_\text{DAC},$$

where \$K_v = 2.2\$ and I have \$V_\text{ref} = 1.9\,\text{V}\$ with TRQ_DAC register configured as 50%. Meanwhile, VM = 13.5V with the motor resistance as 17.5 ohms. Since VM = 13.5V, I've set TRQ_DAC to 50% in order to not hit the rails. Given these parameters, I should be expecting a voltage of 7.6V according to Ohm's Law and a current of 432mA given the equation above but I'm getting values (rather inconsistently too) that are over 10% off especially with current. Am I missing part of my KCL/KVL circuit analysis; that is, is there another element in the loop I'm not accounting for? The datasheet makes it seem not the case.

Comment: I think your question is missing a link to the datasheet and a schematic. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid. Hit the edit link below your question ...

Answer (score 0):

There are no [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8889-q1.pdf) high/low limits given for the Kv parameter- only a typical value. It will vary from unit to unit, and with temperature.

Resistance of the winding may not be exactly nominal and will vary considerably as the coil heats up (about +0.4%/K).

The current mirror approach may lose accuracy as the output voltage approaches the rails.

Your reference voltage may not be exactly as predicted - measuring it directly will reduce the uncertainty, but ground currents from the motor will affect it a bit, worse if the layout is not ideal.

So there are plenty of opportunities for differences from the ideal, and I don’t see a way to estimate the potential Kv variation.

Comment: Hi I thought that too but the “motor” I’m using is just an RL circuit so the nonidealities of a motor aren’t a problem. I forgot to mention that there’s consistently a 100mA difference between what the oscilloscope measures and what the theoretical current should be. So I’m wondering if my circuit analysis is correct or if I’m missing something

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but I see no indication in the datasheet of how accurate Kv is.. 10%? 30%?  It’s probably not 1% or 2%.

Comment: Do you think it’s the FET between VM and AOUT1/BOUT1?? That would explain the .1A drop